# MySQL - Using results from one query to use in another query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's say I have this, that produces 50,000 rows:

```
SELECT photoID FROM photoSearch WHERE photoID BETWEEN 1 AND 50000;
```

I was going to run this query against those photoID's just returned.

```
SELECT COUNT(people) AS totalPeople, people
FROM people
INNER JOIN photopeople ON photoPeople.peopleID = people.PeopleID
WHERE photoid IN ('ID's from results')
GROUP BY people
ORDER BY totalPeople DESC
```

But I understand from others and resources, that the IN clause will not perform well, especially as I could have 100,000 plus photoID's.

Is it a good idea to store the photoID's from the top query in another table (resultsTbl) or in a very long string? If yes to either, do I use a join or a sub-select to query those ID's (in the bottom query), instead of using IN? Or... is there another way that will do the job keeping performance in mind?

Any help on this would be gratefully received.

Comment: Is there a problem doing a join with photoSearch.photoID and adding the where constraint to the second query?

Comment: Apart from I need the results separate. The top query produces my results for showing the photos, which I use a do while loop. The second query, using another do while loop, produces a list of all the people in those photos returned

Answer (score 20, accepted):

1. ***Is it a good idea to store the photoID's from the top query in another table (resultsTbl) or in a very long string?***

   - *In another table:* Generally, no.  If there are a lot of IDs and you perform the top query in other places, then storing it in a cache-ing table could be okay.  Though, for this case, the "top query" is most likely going to remain in memory, so you should probably use a subselect.
   - *In a very long string:* No.  String operations are generally highly CPU intensive.
2. ***If yes to either, do I use a join or a sub-select to query those ID's (in the bottom query), instead of using IN?***

   - Instead of storing it in a temporary table, just do a JOIN to start with (see example below).  In some cases databases will join an `IN(select * from foo)` for you.

---

- #### Using IN(subselect):

  ```
  SELECT     count(people) AS totalPeople
           , people
  FROM       people
  INNER JOIN photopeople ON photoPeople.peopleID = people.PeopleID
  WHERE      photoid IN (select  photoID 
                         from    photoSearch 
                         where   photoID 
                         between 1 AND 50000)
  GROUP BY   people
  ORDER BY   totalPeople DESC
  ```
- #### Using JOIN

  ```
  SELECT     count(people) AS totalPeople
           , people
  FROM       people
  INNER JOIN photopeople ON photoPeople.peopleID = people.PeopleID
  INNER JOIN photoSearch ON photopeople.photoid  = photoSearch.photoID
  WHERE      photoID between 1 AND 50000
  GROUP BY   people
  ORDER BY   totalPeople DESC
  ```

Comment: Nice. You could add the `EXISTS` version.

Comment: Wow, I really appreciate your input @ypercube. I have just tried the "using IN(subselect)" suggestion but it took far too long to process. My real query, on it's own, already takes 1 second to return results. In your suggestion, I am basically doing another search the same, which now makes it 2+ seconds. There must be a quicker way because when I want to add the keywords and events query too, it will take nearly 5 seconds!

Comment: I'm now thinking to store the results, so I can use them in the people  query, the keywords query and the events query... do you agree?

Comment: @MartinG: `JOIN` or `EXISTS` should be faster in MySQL. But it really depends on the indexes you have on the tables.

Comment: If you try `JOIN`, use `count(*)` instead of `count(people)`.

Comment: Okay, I got this working, which gets the search results from a table called searchPhotoResults but it takes 15 seconds to return! SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalPeople, people FROM people
INNER JOIN photopeople ON photoPeople.peopleID = people.PeopleID
INNER JOIN searchPhotoResults ON photopeople.photoid  = searchPhotoResults.photoID
GROUP BY people
ORDER BY totalPeople DESC
LIMIT 5

Comment: and then I added indexing to my searchResults table which took it down to 1.5 seconds... I'd still prefer it to be under 1

Comment: ypercube: The `EXISTS` should also be in there, the query planner should translate most of these to the same execution plan, but it should be added above. I'll modify it when I have time, or go ahead and add it in there.

Comment: Thank-you vol7ron for your detailed answer. I actually stuck the results from the top query in a searchResults table. Then in the second query, which I use in another part of my page, I'm joining my searchResults table to the query to produce the list of names and counts. It produces good results but it could be touch faster. I don't know anything about cache tables, I will have to explore that